# C# Scoped Service Event Handling

Tags: c#, blazor

Wondering if someone can help. I've got a service that's been declared as a Scoped Service and making a Singleton is going to be way more challenging as there's a bunch of dependencies on it at the moment.

What I want to happen is when someone submits a request to the webpage it updates that component in razor for all users within the given tenancy. In the razor page I have the following code:

```
private Action<string, int, int>? pageStateChangedHandler;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    pageStateChangedHandler = HandlePageStateChanged;
    mainService.OnPageStateChanged += pageStateChangedHandler;
    << Ommited for brevity >>
}
private async void HandlePageStateChanged(string detailId, int minusChange, int plusChange)
{
    var changedPage = PageDetails?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == detailId);
    if (changedPage != null)
    {
        changedPage.Incremental += plusChange;
        changedPage.Decremental -= minusChange;
        await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        mainService.OnPageStateChanged -= pageStateChangedHandler;
    }
}
```

Then in the service I have the following code:

```
public event Action<string, int, int> OnPageStateChanged = delegate { };
public mainService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> factory )
    {
        _factory = factory;
        OnPageStateChanged += (detailId, minusChange, plusChange) =>
        {
        };
    }
public async Task<bool> SubmitChange(List<Changes> MainChanges)
{
    << Ommited for brevity >>
    OnPageStateChanged.Invoke(Details.ID, 1, 1);
}
```

I seem to be running into an issue where each user subscribes to the event on the service and the OnPageStateChanged.Invoke is being executed but the razor page isn't seeing the change and updating the HandlePageStateChanged and there is no update to the page for all users just the user that has made the change. Can anyone help with this? I'm sure I'm doing something daft here. Also, this is being run in Blazor.

Comment: Is this Blazor Server? If so, scoped services are not shared between clients.

Comment: Hi Lex, yes it's Blazor Server. Based on that is the only option to go down the Singleton route? I've been looking online and it looks like it's going to be a pain to change that, based on my limited knowledge. I have the tenancy data stored in a single database table so if I were to go down that route, I'd need a way up creating singletons dynamically against the service in question. Is that possible?

Comment: Any service you scope as singleton will be shared among all connected clients. If you have client-specific stuff you probably don't want to store it in a service scoped as singleton unless you're using some type of keyed collection, but it can get messy. This may be slightly out of date, but [here's a good rundown of the various service scopes](https://chrissainty.com/service-lifetimes-in-blazor/).

Comment: thanks Lex, I'll read that to re-understand the differences. I'm a little unsure where to go from here based on your comments. it's just these two integers that I need to get updated for anyone within a given tenancy on this platform

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I managed to get this to work through SignalR rather than try to do something clever in Blazor. I created a custom Hub and connected to that hub for all users in the DB. I just made sure that I created groups to assign to each tenant. I followed this guide mostly: [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Make sure it works when you deploy. There’s been a [long standing authentication bug](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25000) with using SignalR in this fashion with Blazor.